# NullPointer exception while calling a SOAP function

Tags: java, web-services, soap, nullpointerexception

I am trying the following code to run a SOAP method from a web service.

```
public de.externalwebservices.worms.aphiav1_0.AphiaRecord[] getAphiaChildrenByID(int aphiaID, int offset, boolean marine_only) throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
   if (aphiaNameServicePortType == null)
       _initAphiaNameServicePortTypeProxy();
   return aphiaNameServicePortType.getAphiaChildrenByID(aphiaID, offset, marine_only);}
```

That I call in a second class called **WORMSWSDAO** as:

```
public AphiaRecord[] getAphiaChildrenByID(int AphiaID){
    AphiaRecord[] result = new AphiaRecord[0];
    try {
        result = port.getAphiaChildrenByID(AphiaID, 1, false);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then I run it in the main as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

    WORMSWSDAO  wDAO = new WORMSWSDAO();

    AphiaRecord [] result = wDAO.getAphiaChildrenByID(219275);
    System.out.println(result[1].getFamily());


}
```

but after running that all I get is a null pointer exception..

Comment: More info would be helpful. Is **port** variable initialized? Do you instantiate it or inject it using some annotation?

Comment: Show us the stack trace